# How to optimize sql

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

[sql tuning] How to tune in this situation?

erd as above

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdgPn.png)

```sql
SELECT
         store0_.store_id as store_id1_10_,
         store0_.address as address2_10_,
         store0_.business_name as business3_10_,
         store0_.business_number as business4_10_,
         store0_.business_start_date as business5_10_,
         store0_.category_id as category11_10_,
         store0_.name as name6_10_,
         store0_.member_id as member_12_10_,
         store0_.phone as phone7_10_,
         store0_.reason_for_rejection as reason_f8_10_,
         store0_.request_date as request_9_10_,
         store0_.status as status10_10_
        
     from
         store store0_
     inner join
         category category1_
             on store0_.category_id=category1_.category_id
     left outer join
         store_keyword storekeywo2_
             on store0_.store_id=storekeywo2_.store_id
     left outer join
         keyword keyword3_
             on storekeywo2_.keyword_id=keyword3_.keyword_id
     left outer join
         review reviewlist4_
             on store0_.store_id=reviewlist4_.store_id
     left outer join
         likes likeslist5_
             on store0_.store_id=likeslist5_.store_id
     where
         store0_.status='APPROVED'
         AND store0_.name LIKE 'store%'
     group by
         store0_.store_id
     order by
         count(reviewlist4_.review_id) ASC LIMIT 100
    OFFSET 8000
```

where condition always has storestatus

Users can search by selecting a few of storename, categoryname, keywordname, and location.

You can sort by store likes, the highest number of reviews, and the highest review rating.

<Tuning Point>

Reduce the number of joins

I can't reduce it in that situation.. There are many cases where I need the information of the joined table.. Am I doing something wrong with the design..?
If you want to import from there at once, you have to duplicate data from other tables in the store table.

Introduction of index

Storestatus is always the leading condition, so I specified it as an index. However, there are 2-3 types of storestatus values, and most of them are approved stores, so the index effect is insignificant.

Column processing in orderby

In this way, the index will not be removed. If sort is performed, if there is not enough data in memory, it will lead to disk io operation. I know it will have a bad effect on performance, but I can't help it because I have to sort by the number of reviews.

I can't help it because I can't help it. How can I say that I'm going to put my hands on the best query?

Reduce the number of joins

I can't reduce it in that situation.. There are many cases where I need the information of the joined table.. Am I doing something wrong with the design..? If you want to import from there at once, you have to duplicate data from other tables in the store table.

Introduction of index

Storestatus is always the leading condition, so I specified it as an index. However, there are 2-3 types of storestatus values, and most of them are approved stores, so the index effect is insignificant.

Column processing in orderby

In this way, the index will not be removed. If sort is performed, if there is not enough data in memory, it will lead to disk io operation. I know it will have a bad effect on performance, but I can't help it because I have to sort by the number of reviews.

Comment: So, you are joining the keywords, because a user might want to filter by keyword? But in the query you are showing there is no restriction on keyword and you are only selecting columns of the store table. So how would you filter?

Comment: Please show another example or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Indexes recommended, below
- Remove any `LFET JOINs` for which you are not using any of the columns. This appears to be all but `reviewlist4_`.  (They will be looked at, and the MySQL Optimizer does not seem smart enough to remove them for you.)  This seems to be all of your `LEFT OUTER JOINs`.  As you generate the query, add on the Joins that are needed.
- `LIMIT 100 OFFSET 8000` -- will be slow.  The indexes (even the ones below) will probably not prevent gathering all the potential output rows, skipping over 8000 (one by one), and finally, delivering the desired 100.
- Is some framework generating this query?  Does it let you write "raw" SQL?
- Is this "1-to-many"?  `ON store0_.store_id=reviewlist4_.store_id`.  If so it may be possible to turn this query inside out -- to get the `COUNTs` *before* doing all the `JOINing`, thereby avoiding the costly "explode (Joins) + implode (Group by)".
- `LEFT` with `reviewlist4_` may be inappropriate; you might get zeros.

Tentative indexes:

```
  category1_:  INDEX(category_id)
  storekeywo2_:  INDEX(store_id,  keyword_id)
  keyword3_:  INDEX(keyword_id)
  reviewlist4_:  INDEX(store_id,  review_id)
  likeslist5_:  INDEX(store_id)
```

Many-to-many mapping tables should be optimized by having
two 2-column composite indexes and no auto_inc.
See [*Optimal relation*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Further comments:

- It sounds like you need multiple indexes, each being composite and starting with `status`.
- The `ORDER BY` cannot be optimized other than by finding a list of `store_ids` *before* gathering all the other stuff.  Something like:

  ```
    SELECT ...
        FROM (
            SELECT store_id, COUNT(..) AS ct
                FROM store_id1_10
                JOIN as little as possible
                WHERE as little as possible
                ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... OFFSET
             ) AS stores
        JOIN store_id1_10 as store0_
                 USING(store_id)
        JOIN any other tables needed ...
        ORDER BY ct
  ```

(this example is probably incomplete and incorrect.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `EXPLAIN {your query}` to see query information and if some indexes may be adjusted or is missing.
2. You can always split query into multiple: One main query with `join` but without `left join`; Than separate queries with `SELECT {neededInformation} FROM {table} WHERE category_id IN (:idsFromMainQuery)`.
3. Check RDBMS specific optimization strategies. You should tell yourself what you want to optimize: query speed or returned quantity of information.